# Alignment issue with CSS and Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, leaflet, dc.js

My leaflet map is covering the title of the map which is supposed to be just above the map. I am using CSS and Bootstrap to align page elements. See the image: [image] Here is the code:

```
  <style type="text/css">
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
img {
width:97%; /* you can use % */
height: auto;
}
div#location {
  width:600px;
  height:400px;
}

div#datatable {height:700px; overflow-y:scroll; width: 425px word-wrap: break-word;}
td.dc-table-label {display:none;}
span.dc-data-count {font-size:.5em;}
span.dc-data-count {font-weight: normal;}
table#media-table {
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```
  <div class="container" style="padding-top:20px">

<h2 class="page-title">Ivan Doig Archive Explorer <span class="dc-data-count">Showing <span class="filter-count"></span> of <span class="total-count"></span> photographs {<a href="javascript:dc.filterAll(); dc.renderAll();">reset</a>}</span>
</h2>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <strong><span id="datatable"></span>Media</strong>
          <table class="table table-hover" id="media-table"></table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" id="location">
          <strong><span id="map"></span>Location</strong>
        </div>
    </div>
```

References to the datatable and the map are as follows:

```
var map = dc.leafletMarkerChart("#location", groupname)
var dataTable = dc.dataTable("#media-table", groupname)
```

The map is supposed to line up with the top of the "filmstrip" and it has a title of "Location" just like "Media". This will allow for adding summary stats at the top of each element.

Comment: Try shifting it down with `margin-top`.

Comment: I just tried adding:     `div#location {
      margin-top: 20;
      width:600px;
      height:400px;
    }` and had the same result.

Comment: Where is the title supposed to be?

Comment: does it help if you add this style? `#map { display: block; }`

Comment: adding  `#map { display: block; }` did not help.

Comment: Are you loading the leaflet map in the `<span id="map" />`?

Comment: I may be doing just that, I'm a bit confused about where I'm loading the leaflet map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dc.leaflet.js is going to take over the entire `<div>` it's given in its constructor, so just move the title out of the div, right?

Since this means the map is not taking up the entire bootstrap column, we'll need to put it in its own child div.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <strong><span id="datatable"></span>Media</strong>
      <table class="table table-hover" id="media-table"></table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" id="location-column">
      <strong><span id="map"></span>Location</strong>
      <div id="location">
    </div>
</div>
```

You'll see a lot of examples that put other stuff inside the div that dc.js charts use. It's mostly useful for the reset/display filter controls, so that the chart can find and change them. It's makes the layout confusing.

Another solution may be to add to the top margin using [marginMixin.margins()](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.marginMixin.html#margins__anchor):

```
map.margins({top: 100, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0}); // or whatever you need
```

It may be that dc.js behaves better with respect to those extra elements than dc.leaflet.js does, or it may just be that dc.js has default margins while dc.leaflet.js [zeros them out](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.leaflet.js/blob/9c04221927b991d7a5eb9f627634577435be3b88/src/leafletBase.js#L4).

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not really ideal in terms of structure I would make use of the spans to push down the starting point of the map element.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <strong><span id="datatable"></span>Media</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <table class="table table-hover" id="media-table"></table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" id="location">
        <strong><span id="map"></span>Location</strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay that pushed the map down to where it should be but the title is still behind it (I can see it load first before the map covers it up).

Comment: @mutanthumb ah I see, really that should be enough to work but I would have to see it live to evaluate the css

Comment: I'll try to get the Plunk working so you can see it in action, right now I just have it running from my laptop.

Comment: I'm not sure why my images and map aren't pulling into Plunker but here it is: https://plnkr.co/edit/Odsej7W2xzKGgnidhyDV